# Two variables comparison, one-to-four possible outputs

Tags: linux, bash, variables, if-statement

I have two variables:

```
a=`echo 262832 6469180`
b=`echo 262832 263159 6469180 6469390`
```

hence:

```
echo $a
262832 6469180

echo $b
262832 263159 6469180 6469390
```

"b" represents four UTM coordinates, which are arranged from west to east, and from south to north (ie, W E S N). Variable "b" contains "a" only in two positions. Thus, after the comparison between "b" and "a" I need to print "1" and "3". The problem is that I also need to replace "1" and "3" by "W" and "S".

I do the comparison as follows:

```
if [[ $b == *"$a"* ]]
then
   echo "a is in b"
else
   echo "not there"
fi
```

but don't get the right idea to do the output replacement (it should be by columns as far as I understand).

Any pointers are welcomed,

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: You're trying to represent a list of values using a whitespace-delimited string. That's a sure sign that you should choose a language with proper data-structure support, not shell.

Comment: Use arrays instead of strings, so you can easily loop over them. `a=(262832 6469180)`

Comment: thanks to all for your comments, expected output would be `W S` because `b` represents `W E S N`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with [`bash` arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays):

```
wesn=( W E S N )
a=( 262832 6469180 )
b=( 262832 263159 6469180 6469390 )
for ((i=0; i < ${#b[@]}; i++)); do
    for ((j=0; j < ${#a[@]}; j++)); do
        [ "${b[i]}" == "${a[j]}" ] && echo "${wesn[i]}"
    done
done
```

It just compares member by member and returns letter mapped in `wesn`.